# How would I capture a string using fscanf?

Tags: c, string, capture, scanf

I've got a file that is formatted like this

```
A New Day Has Come (Radio Remix); 239
Ten Days; 227
Goodbye's (The Saddest Word); 198
Prayer; 313
I Surrender; 271
At Last; 209
Sorry For Love; 301
```

How would I use `fscanf` to grab the string, and also the number following the semicolon? I tried this

```
for(track = 0; track < albums[size].num_tracks; ++track){

    fscanf(fileptr,"%s;%i",albums[size].tracks[track].name,albums[size].tracks[track].length);

    //print out the tracks
    printf("Track number %i : %s", track, &albums[size].tracks[track].name);
}
```

However, when the printf happens, the whole string isn't printed, rather something like

```
Track number 0 : A 
Track number 1 : New
Track number 2 : Day
etc...
```

So as you can see, the code is capturing the individual words for some reason, rather than the entire string before the semi colon. Which expression would I use to grab the entire string? Edited for spelling

Comment: Do you have to use fscanf? Since a semicolon is separating the text and the number, why can't you use strtok function instead? Here is an example of strtok http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

Comment: I think I do need to use fscanf :( damn C projects

Comment: When you use %s, it tries to read string until a non-whitespace character is reached. So you will get each words at a time.

Comment: any way to avoid that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While `fscanf` might not be the best function to use in this case, formally one can still be use it to grab the string that ends with `;` by using the following format specifier

```
fscanf(fileptr, "%[^;];%i",
  albums[size].tracks[track].name,
  &albums[size].tracks[track].length);
```

This will require the input file to adhere to very strict format requirements though. Note also that if your `albums[size].tracks[track].length` is an `int` object, then `&` operator is required before `albums[size].tracks[track].length`. When `%i` format specifier is used in `fscanf` it requies a *pointer* to `int` as argument.

Also, your `printf` does not look right. It should be

```
printf("Track number %i : %s", track, albums[size].tracks[track].name);
```

That `&` before `albums[size].tracks[track].name` is not supposed to be there.

Comment: for some reason this segfaulted :(

Comment: @Zack: The reason must be in something you are not showing. Is the recepient buffer large enough for the string?

Comment: care to explain what %[^;] means?

Comment: @Zack: `%[S]` means "read while characters belong to the set S". `%[^S]` means "read while characters do not belong to the set S". So `%[^;]` means "read until you hit `;`".

Comment: Also when you scan albums[size].tracks[track].length... make sure to add & in front of the variable.. like this so value gets actually written into the memory of length &albums[size].tracks[track].length

Comment: @Zack: It segfaults becuase you forgot `&` before the integer recipient variable. In `fscanf` the `%i` format specifier requires a *pointer* to `int` as argument.

Comment: Ok, I messed around with this enough so it is finally working. Props for the %[] advice, that was key, although you were right, it is VERY picky. The problem I believe was a newline or something like that throwing off the formatting. Finally got it though :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't `fscanf` is for formatted data. Your data isn't really formatted in a way friendly to `fscanf`. You'd be better off reading the whole line and then just searching for the semicolon.

Comment: If I end up having to do this, how would I parse the line once I grab it. It is not a stretch to say I am a complete C newb. Perl/python usually